# Equivalent to produce field glow in other browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was long using this to add a glow to focused fields, I accessed my page from Firefox for the first time and realized it doesn't work on it, and most likely not on explorer either.

```
border: 1px solid #E68D29;
outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
outline-offset: -2px;
outline-style: auto;
outline-width: 5px;
```

I had copy pasted it from another page so I'm not quite sure how it works. What is the equivalent for Firefox or Explorer? I mean how do I make a similar glow in other browsers? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798919/how-to-simulate-chrome-safari-border-around-active-input-or-textarea-on-other-ele

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webkit treats "outline-style: auto;" differently than other browsers. If you want to get behavior that's more similar across browsers I'd recommend you use box-shadow instead. It won't apply to older browsers (IE8 and earlier, or FF3.0 and earlier) but otherwise should be the same.

Using [this code](http://jsbin.com/ijuhi5/4/edit)

```
  input {
    border: 1px solid #E68D29;
  }
  input.focus {
    border-color: #439ADC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #439ADC; /* IE9, Chrome 10+, FF4.0+, Opera 10.9+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #439ADC; /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #439ADC; /* FF3.5+ */
  }
```

I was able to produce a result that shows cross-browser glow in [IE9+, FF4+, Chrome 10+, and Safari 5+](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/626d347c44ea87eb48a85002b6913ad1de667466).

Option 2) You could experiment with using some combination of outline (which will show in Webkit) and box-shadow (for other browsers).

Option 3) Use a library like [Formalize CSS](http://formalize.me/) to take care of the cross-platform input styling for you. The results are pretty impressive.