# What is auto outline in Webkit?

Tags: css, webkit

What does `auto` mean when I write:

```
:focus {
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
```

It is not documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) and I cannot find documentation elsewhere.

Comment: Better documentation for outline properties is now available on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the shorthand for the [`outline-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#outline0) properties; `auto` represents the value for `outline-style` and `auto` itself means that it's up to the browser to decide what to do based on the context of the element.

Comment: Thanks. But what are the rules for determining what `auto` will be calculated to?

Comment: Its up to the browser, your example is the default :focus for webkit which seems to be a special case; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686580/equivalent-to-produce-field-glow-in-other-browsers

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that in IE `auto` doesn't show anything, and you'll have to explicitly declare what type of border you want to use. Alex K's link is a good demonstration of how other popular browsers work.